# Query for a table where FK can be null

Tags: sql, oracle

A simple case: we have a main table (id, name, dictionary_id) and a dictionary table (id, name). The dictionary_id is the FK related with the dictionary table. NULL values are possible for dictionary_id.

I need to show:
id, name, dictionary_name
if dictionary_id is null (in this case dictionary_name is empty) or
dictionary_id comes from a list (e.g. from subquery).

Thanks,
Jacek

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an outer join:

```
select mt.id, mt.name, dt.name as dictionary_name
from main_table mt
  left join dictionary_table dt on mt.dictionary_id = dt.id;
```